# discord.py run only certain cog

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm programming my discord bot, and I want to have a different command set when you send a DM to the bot. I have a `DM` cog and a `CHANNELS` cog. In my `event.on_message`, my code is:

```py
if message.channel.id in _allowed_channels:
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

is there some way to do something like this:

```py
if message.guild == None: # Direct messages
    await DM.process_commands(message)
else:
    await CHANNELS.process_commands(message)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!
discord.ext.commands has a check:

```py
from discord.ext import commands
#Code...
@bot.command()
@commands.dm_only() #The Check
async def _cmd(self, ctx):
    #Code...
```

You can even use the cog_check:

```
class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    #Code...
    async def cog_check(ctx):
        return True
    #Code...
```